# Return boolean from Mouselistener

Tags: java, swing, button, jframe, boolean

The class "board" wants to know if any of his objects in the array is clicked. So he have a function

```
private void CheckButtons()
{
    for(int y = 0; y < yheight; y++)
    {
        for(int x = 0; x < xwith; x++)
        {
            if(_boardNodes[x][y].NodeClick())
            {
                MoveIfICan(x,y);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This "board" class have a function that is called by its own thread to always check if a button is clicked. It does that by the above function that calls a inner function of the class Node

What i want to do, is a way to return true if the label is clicked. The function in the node class looks like this

```
    public boolean NodeClick()
{
    _isClicked = false;
    _clickAbleLabel.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) 
        {
            _isClicked = true;
            System.out.println("Clicked button respons");
        }
    });
    System.out.println("Is Clicked: " + _isClicked);
    return _isClicked;

}
```

This dont work at all. So i need tips on a better solution than this failed one. 
Note: I always get a "Clicked button respons" but the _isClicked will remain false at all time.

//Thanks

Comment: Do you understand that the `mouseClicked` method will only be executed *when a click occurs*, which will be after the `NodeClick` method has already returned?

Comment: Swing is an event driven environment.  That is, an event occurs and you react to it.  `NodeClick` will always return `false`.  There simply isn't enough information available to make a real suggestion, other then the fact that within the `mouseClicked` event, you should be performing what ever action is required to highlight the fact that this node has just being clicked...

Comment: ok thanks. I will change the logics of the program then :p

Comment: Unrelated: Please learn java naming conventions and stick to them.